# how to JOIN on not null

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, php

Im trying to create referals system. I am doing that by passing into during database every registaration all referals (first, second and third "stage").

to clarify, if user ID 3 registers from ref. of user ID 2, and user ID 2 was registered from ref of ID 1, the values for user ID 3 would look like:

```
`r1` = 2, `r2` = 1, `r3` = NULL
```

To read from database who is registered using some id's ref link with whole path, I figured out this query:

```
SELECT `sub`.`id` AS first,`sub2`.`id` AS `second`,`sub3`.`id` AS `third`

FROM `users` AS `usr` 

JOIN `users` AS `sub` ON `sub`.`r1` = `usr`.`id` 
JOIN `users` AS `sub2` ON `sub2`.`r2` = `usr`.`id` 
JOIN `users` AS `sub3` ON `sub3`.`r3` = `usr`.`id`

WHERE `usr`.`id` = :CurrentUserId ;
```

(:CurrentUserId is PDO placeholder for PHP for int value)

Although, its problematic, as it works only for accounts with all 3 refers into past, so people with only first line or first and second line, but without third will not be listed. In other words, that would mean, if there is user, that has following values

```
r1 = 2, r2 = 1, r3 = NULL
```

is not listed. It works if r3 is equal to something.

I could work it around by sending 3 queries to database, but I am sure, that there is better way.

(Im not very expirienced with databases)

Comment: Have you tried using `LEFT` joins?

Comment: As ypercube said, `LEFT JOIN` is what you need.  The `JOIN` implies `INNER JOIN` and makes it mandatory that a record is there but a `LEFT JOIN` will allow it to be null if it's not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use left joins instead of inner joins so that records from users will still display even if r1, r2, and r3 are `null`:

```
SELECT sub.id AS first,sub2.id AS second,sub3.id AS third

FROM users AS usr

LEFT JOIN users AS sub ON sub.r1 = usr.id 
LEFT JOIN users AS sub2 ON sub2.r2 = usr.id
LEFT JOIN users AS sub3 ON sub3.r3 = usr.id

WHERE usr.id = :CurrentUserId ;
```

However, based on your example I think you may need the following query instead, changing the join conditions so that sub, sub2, and sub3 represent referred users:

```
SELECT sub.id AS first,sub2.id AS second,sub3.id AS third

FROM users AS usr

LEFT JOIN users AS sub ON sub.id = usr.r1
LEFT JOIN users AS sub2 ON sub2.id = usr.r2
LEFT JOIN users AS sub3 ON sub3.id = usr.r3

WHERE usr.id = :CurrentUserId ;
```

Comment: thank you! this works, apparently I need to learn DBs more :)

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the condition you expressed in English:

```
JOIN `users` AS `sub` ON `sub`.`r1` = `usr`.`id` 
JOIN `users` AS `sub2` ON `sub2`.`r2` = `usr`.`id` OR `sub2`.`r2` IS NULL
JOIN `users` AS `sub3` ON `sub3`.`r3` = `usr`.`id` OR `sub3`.`r3` IS NULL
```

Comment: your solution works too, but the @dav3ypants anwser seems more correct.

Comment: I don't think a solution can be _more_ or _less_ correct; it's either correct or not. If two solutions give you the expected results then they're both correct, though semantically these two solutions are different. (I'm not asking for an upvote or acceptance, I just want to state the obvious.)

Comment: I would upvote both, but look at my reputation, i rarely use this stackexchange forum ;)